# Mapping and merging in dask without loading to memory

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I have two files that I am not able to load on my RAM (above 100GB).

Both files are in a similar format, for example:

```
A  8
B  6
C  9
```

And

```
AC  8
BA  6
CQ  35
```

I also have a dictionary that will include my mapping, for example

```
alias_dict = {"A": "AC", "B": "BA", "C": "CQ"}
```

What I want to do, is simply to apply the dictionary over the first dataframe and then merge between both dataframes so that in this example, my expected output would be

```
AC  8
BA  6
```

I try to achieve this with the following code

```
pileup_df['identifier'] = pileup_df.identifier.map(lambda identifier: alias_dict[identifier], meta=('identifier', str))
pileup_df.compute()
lists_df['identifier'] = lists_df.identifier.map(lambda identifier: alias_dict[identifier], meta=('identifier', str))
lists_df.compute()

intersection_df = dd.merge(pileup_df, lists_df, on=['identifier', 'position'])
intersection_df = intersection_df[['identifier', 'position']]
intersection_df.compute()
```

The problem is the conversion only takes place if I specify `pileup_df.compute()` and `lists_df.compute()` like it's written in the code above but this actually load to memory these dataframes.
When I remove the `compute` statements I mentioned above my dataframe remaining in his unconverted form.

Just for clarity, the code that isn't working as expected is

```
pileup_df.identifier.map(lambda identifier: alias_dict[identifier], meta=('identifier', str))
lists_df.identifier.map(lambda identifier: alias_dict[identifier], meta=('identifier', str))

intersection_df = dd.merge(pileup_df, lists_df, on=['identifier', 'position'])
intersection_df = intersection_df[['identifier', 'position']]
intersection_df.compute()
```

Is there a way to apply this conversion and merge without first loading the converted dataframe to memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have some misunderstanding about handling dask objects - let me try to clarify.

An expression like

```
pileup_df.identifier.map(lambda identifier: alias_dict[identifier], meta=('identifier', str))
```

produces a lazy output object, in this case a series, and nothing is computed. But if you do not assign this thing to a variable or back into a column of a dataframe, then not even the lazy process is kept.

Instead, as you had in the first example

```
pileup_df['identifier'] = pileup_df.identifier.map(lambda identifier: alias_dict[identifier], meta=('identifier', str))
```

now the definition of `pileup_df` is changed to include the mapping of the column, but the dataframe is still lazy and not loaded into memory (which is good!).

A line like

```
pileup_df.compute()
```

computes your object, including any changes you made by assignment, and puts it into memory. This might fill up your memory - but you, again, didn't actually assign the output. `.compute()` doe *not* change the object it is applied to, but instead creates a new object, here a Pandas dataframe.

Your code should perhaps be

```
pileup_df['identifier'] = pileup_df.identifier.map(lambda identifier: alias_dict[identifier], meta=('identifier', str))
lists_df['identifier'] = lists_df.identifier.map(lambda identifier: alias_dict[identifier], meta=('identifier', str))
intersection_df = dd.merge(pileup_df, lists_df, on=['identifier', 'position'])
intersection_df = intersection_df[['identifier', 'position']]
result = intersection_df.compute()
```

Are you sure the end result fits in memory? Note that you didn't mention the scheduler you are using here; you might need considerably more memory than just the size of the output, for various intermediate results. Often, it's better to immediately perform whatever final work you need to - aggregation before the compute, or output to file. Examples:

```
result = intersection_df.sum(...).compute()  # aggregation
intersection_df.to_parquet(...). # output to file
```

Comment: In case that my goal is just to output `intersection_df` to a file, could I skip using `intersection_df.compute()`?
Also, for outputting the df to a file I used `to_csv`, how does it differ from `to_parquet`?

Comment: Yes, skip compute - I think I said this. "how does it differ" - one makes CSV files, one parquet format files. They have different arguments, see the docstrings.